# Why these elements are not inline?

Tags: html, css

Why the lights, seatbelt, gas, engine and lock are not inline?
I tried to put style: inline-block but is the same
I don't have any ideas what can i do, i tried a lot of things but it was for nothing.

```js
            function update_speed(speed, maxspeed) {
                if (speed > maxspeed) maxspeed = speed;
                if (speed < 50) {
                    document.querySelector("#speedBar").style = "border-bottom-color: green; border-right-color: green;";
                }

                if (speed > 50 && speed < 100) {
                    document.querySelector("#speedBar").style = "border-bottom-color: yellow; border-right-color: yellow;";
                }

                if (speed > 100) {
                    document.querySelector("#speedBar").style = "border-bottom-color: red; border-right-color: red;";
                }

                document.querySelector("#speedBar").style.transform = `rotate(${45 + (parseInt(speed) / parseInt(maxspeed)) * 100 * 1.8}deg)`;
                document.getElementById("speedText").innerHTML = speed;
            }

            function update_gas(gas) {
                document.querySelector("#gas span").style.height = parseInt(gas) + "%";
            }

            function updateaza_usi(value) {
                if (value == 0) {
                    document.getElementById("lock").style.background = "#af0000";
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("lock").style.background = "green";
                }
            }

            function update_engine(value) {
                if (value == 0) {
                    document.getElementById("engine").style.background = "#af0000";
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("engine").style.background = "green";
                }
            }
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  user-select: none;
}

.global {
  display: none;
}

.app {
  position: absolute;
  right: 2.5em;
  top: 0;
  margin-top: 46.5%;
}

@media (max-height: 1077px) {
  .app {
    margin-top: 45.5%;
  }
}

.round-progress {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.round-overflow {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: -25px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}

.bar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 9px solid #bdbdbd;
  transition: all 0.1s linear;
}

.round-info {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 50%;
  padding: 1%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.icon {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 8px;
  margin: 10px 12px 0 5px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
}
.icon i {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 11;
  font-size: 15px;
}
.icon span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.info {
  position: absolute;
}

.info.player {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  margin-top: 51%;
  right: 1em;
  text-align: right;
}

@media (max-height: 1077px) {
  .info.player {
    margin-top: 50%;
  }
}

.info.player #status {
  clear: both;
}
.info.player #status ul {
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}
.info.player #status ul li {
  float:left;
}

.info.player #status ul li#gas span {
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #ff8000 0%, #ff8000 100%);
}
.info.player #status ul li#gas.dead {
  animation: trew-pulse 100ms infinite;
}
.info.player #status ul li#gas.dead span {
  height: 0 !important;
}
.info.player #status ul li#gas.dead i.fas:before {
  content: "\f714";
}

.info.player #status ul li#seatbelt span {
  background: rgba(68, 56, 56, 0.35);
}
.info.player #status ul li#lights span {
  background: rgba(68, 56, 56, 0.35);
}
.info.player #status ul li#engine span {
  background: rgba(68, 56, 56, 0.35);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Speedometer</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400,700,900&display=swap" id="font" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.7.2/animate.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="global" style="display: block;">
            <div class="app" id="placeholder1">
                <div class="round-progress">
                    <div class="round-overflow">
                        <div class="bar" id="speedBar"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="round-info">
                        <br />
                        <a id="kilometers" style="font-size: 15px; font-family: 'Montserrat'; font-weight: 700; text-shadow: 0 0 4px black; color: white; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px; -webkit-text-stroke-color: black;">Speed (km/h)</a>
                        <br />
                        <a id="speedText" style="font-size: 50px; font-family: 'Montserrat'; font-weight: 500; text-shadow: 0 0 4px black; color: white; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px; -webkit-text-stroke-color: black;">0</a>
                    </div>
                <div class="info player">
                    <div id="status" style="display: inline-block;">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="icon" id="lights">
                                <i><img src="https://i.imgur.com/ry04rTj.png" /></i><span></span>
                            </li>

                            <li class="icon" id="seatbelt">
                                <i><img src="https://i.imgur.com/bTv5mwk.png" /></i><span></span>
                            </li>

                            <li class="icon" id="gas">
                                <i><img src="https://i.imgur.com/0Wrhhis.png" /></i><span></span>
                            </li>

                            <li class="icon" id="engine">
                                <i><img src="https://i.imgur.com/65v3o9w.png" /></i><span></span>
                            </li>

                            <li class="icon" id="lock">
                                <i><img src="https://i.imgur.com/biJ8RJX.png" /></i><span></span>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="script.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/cferdinandi/saferInnerHTML@1/dist/saferInnerHTML.polyfills.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: setting your ul as `display:flex` will make them all align

Comment: @MaxiGui doesn't work

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) license, for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Comment: Please do not deface your question, especially after someone, a volunteer, has put in effort on their own free time to answer it. Your defacing the question, rendering it and the answer useless to future visitors, is impolite to the answerer and site members in the extreme.

Answer (score 3):

`round-overflow` is set to 200px, and everything is inside of that, so they are "trapped" by that width. if you increase the width of `round-overflow`, they will spread out into 1 line. Of course that might create new issues, but that is the problem.

Possible/partial fix:

add width:

```
.info.player {
    width: 100%;
}
```

change margin:

```
.icon {
    margin: 10px 0px 0 1px;
}
```

There are some unusual things going on that I didn't look into.

Comment: And there is not any fix?

Comment: Possible fix added.